# Can I embed the "Google My Business" opening hours to my Brizy website? (HTML output)

Tags: google-my-business-api, google-my-business

Is there a way to embed the Google My Business opening hours to my Brizy Cloud website? Brizy has an embed element, which I believe should help me with it but not totally sure.
[screenshot Brizy Cloud code embed element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6L3q.jpg)

My intention is to have the GMB hours displayed here:
http://www.speedyheadshots.com/contact (or to actually create a separate page for it)

So I basically need an HTML output of the GMB opening hours. Does that exist?

I looked at this: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/appearance/structured-data/local-business but it's a little over my head.

Answer (score 0):

You basically have two options, it depends on your use case (e.g. if this is only for one page for one location or if this is a service for many locations).

First option is to hard code opening hours into an infowindow: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Second option is to query the Places API for the [place details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details) and then populate the infowindow. For this, you would either have to know the Place ID or use the [find place](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place) method to find the location.